# \b and \a didnt work on xcode, but terminal did. Why is it happen?

Tags: c

When I studied C language about escape 
sequence, `\b` and `\a` didn't work on Xcode. But if I use terminal instead of Xcode, `\b` and `\a` work well.

Why is it happening??

Comment: Beause xcode doesn't support them while the terminal you used supports them?

Comment: The working of `\a` and `\b` depend on the output terminal. In fact (since it sounds like you're on a Mac), you can switch the 'audible bell' on and off.

Answer (score 0):

This is because *Xcode is not the terminal*.

These sequences (known as *escape sequences*), `\a` and `\b` work *only in the terminal*.

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (emphasis mine):

> In computing, ANSI escape codes (or escape sequences) are a method using in-band signaling to control the formatting, color, and other output options on video **text terminals**. To encode this formatting information, certain sequences of bytes are embedded into the text, which **the terminal looks for and interprets as commands**, not as character codes.

Comment: @햄스터, `\n` is more universal, it works not only in the terminal