# When running c language on vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        printf("Be Happy!\n");
        printf("My\tFriend\n");
    
        printf("Goot\bd\tchance\n");
        printf("Cow\rW\a\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in8Tf.png)

The result for the above code comes out like an image,
so please tell me how to make it output without a red tag.

```
Gootd   chance    =>    Good    chance
```

I'm a newbie please help me  :(

Comment: The terminal used doesn't handle backspace `\b` or alert `\a` escape sequences, simple as that.

Comment: in what terminal application? VS Code's integrated terminal? if so, with what [terminal profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823491/b-and-a-didnt-work-on-xcode-but-terminal-did-why-is-it-happen

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend try removing the escape sequences first It may not be handling them well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).